# Change ASP.Net Label text colour if contains '-'

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to change the text/font colour of my ASP.net label if it contains a '-' symbol.

This is a for a percentage change label so negative numbers need to be green and positive red.

I keep getting *TypeError: document.getElementById(....) is null*

I know window.onLoad isn't best practice, this is just to get it tested quickly.

Can anyone advise what I've done wrong..going round in circles.

```
window.onload = fillDays;

function fillDays() {
    var change = document.getElementById("<%=lblPercentageDifferenceToFillReqCurrentVsPreviousMonth %>").value;

    if (change.indexOf(char) = '-') {
        document.getElementById("<%=lblPercentageDifferenceToFillReqCurrentVsPreviousMonth %>").style.color = "green";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("<%=lblPercentageDifferenceToFillReqCurrentVsPreviousMonth %>").style.color = "red";
    }
    console.log("fillDays")
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `ClientID`

```
var change = document.getElementById("<%= lblPercentageDifferenceToFillReqCurrentVsPreviousMonth.ClientID %>").value;
```

Assuming that it is an actual Control like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="lblPercentageDifferenceToFillReqCurrentVsPreviousMonth" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: The control is a label, assuming using .ClientID works the same with them?

Comment: Yes, it will work the same. But then you have to use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`

Comment: Great that now pulls the value, thanks! Just isn't picking up the '-' symbol to change the font colour to green or red etc

Comment: `indexOf` returns an integer, you have to use `if (change.indexOf(char) > -1)`